# getElementById working in Chrome but not Firefox?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox

Ahoy,

I'm fairly new to web dev, so I'm sure many of you will facepalm here.

The markup:

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>this is an example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="id1">Some text here</div>
    <div id="id2">Some other text here</div>

</body>
```

The JS:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var id1 = document.getElementById("id1");
    var id2 = document.getElementById("id2");
    console.log(id1);
    console.log(id2);
}
```

In Chrome I get what I expect printed out to the console. In Firefox I get null. ??

Comment: there are two missing semicolons in line 2 and 3. May be this is causing the error in Firefox

Comment: @wilsotobianco: Semicolons are optional.

Comment: [This](https://jsfiddle.net/x86cwh4e/) works in Firefox _43.0.3_

Comment: For me also it's working

Comment: One Suggestion Try including the script file after the body tag and check